# How to append LD_LIBRARY_PATH permanently on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've modify `/etc/rc.local` to append `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on every boot.
But it doesn't run automatically after reboot and run `bash`.

How can I append `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` permanently?

Comment: Create your own `.conf` file in  `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` instead.

Comment: @alvits Thank you! I've command `ldconfig`, and it works.